# Maximize clusters of points from coordinate data

Tags: qgis, clustering, optimization

So I am definitely new to the GIS world, so bear with me if I don't know the best way to articulate my problem.  That said, I am ready to learn, I would definitely welcome any direction that you all could point me in.

**The problem:**
I have a set of coordinate points (just three attributes: name, lat, long).  I hope to identify the minimum number of regions (circles with a predefined radius) that would be required to encompass XX percent of the sites (Where XX is configurable).

**Initial thoughts:** My thoughts were to first create clusters (of set size) of all data points, then sort the clusters by the number of points they enclose.  That way I can just count the number of clusters needed (in order of priority) until they represent the desired XX percent of the points.

Thus far I have tried to do some research, but I haven't found any resources where the clustering is done within a set radius. (I have found plenty where the number of clusters is set, and the size is variable - I need the reverse of that.)

I have tried using QGIS, but I am open to any suggestions.  I am new to GIS, but I have a decent knowledge of programming if that could be of any help.

Comment: I did a bit more searching and it would appear that the crux of what I am looking for is "distance-based clustering".  However, I cannot seem to find an open/published algorithm (see the end of the section here: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#distancebasedclustering)

Answer (score 1):

Given your initial thoughts I'd take a look at [scipy.cluster.hierarchy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.hierarchy.html#module-scipy.cluster.hierarchy) to start with (or the equivalent in [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#hierarchical-clustering)) to build the clusters based on distance.

For instance, given a `numpy.array` of coordinates - `coords` you could build a cluster based on distance like so:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy
import collections

labels = scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fclusterdata(
    coords,
    threshold, #The distance of whether or not an object is in the cluster
    criterion='distance', #cluster based on distance
    method='complete' #method complete means all points must be within threshold distance of one another to be in the same cluster
)

cluster_count = np.bincount(labels) # count the number of entities in each cluster
sorted_labels = np.argsort(cluster_count)
sorted_labels = sorted_labels[sorted_labels != 0] #hierarchy starts labels at 0, so you want to get rid of it
sorted_count = cluster_count[sorted_labels]

progressive_sum = np.cumsum(sorted_count)
labels_you_care_about = sorted_labels[progressive_sum > number_points_excluded]

points_covered = coords[np.in1d(labels, labels_you_care_about)]

#And from here you can find the centroid and so on
```

For a potentially better solution you might need to look into [Genetic Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) with a package like [pyevolve](http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/0_6rc1/intro.html#download-sec) which should give you better results. It might be worth asking this across on Stack Overflow as well clu